# Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse on mobile device, works when I shrink desktop browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an index.html and require bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js via cdn. When I collapse the browser on my desktop, the navbar collapses properly. When I go to the site on my mobile device, everything is responsive EXCEPT for the navbar.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="the-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stuff</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#what-we-do"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>  About CSC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#how-we-do-it"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  The Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="#the-plan"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>  The Methods</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-us"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  Let's Chat</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  ... some content ...

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and the navbar related css in style.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .navbar .glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }
}

#the-navbar {
  background-color: #2548AE;
  border: none;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#the-navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#the-navbar a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#the-navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #FFF solid;
}
```

Does anyone see a reason as to why the navbar collapses properly on my desktop but not when I load the page on my mobile device?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `user-scalable=yes` Or even better, provide us with a fiddle.

Comment: @Aaron sure I'll try that, thank you. Also, here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/txdavidtx/0nnqx17c/ I'm not sure how to emulate mobile, but you can see that it works in the window.

Comment: @txdavidtx I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?